# Can I transfer a call from the iPhone to Facetime on the mac?

Tags: iphone, macos, facetime, continuity

Using Yosemite, can I transfer a call from the iPhone to Facetime on the mac?  I know it is possible to go from FaceTime on the mac to the iPhone.  I want to go the other direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently not possible (iOS 8, OS X 10.10.3).

A similar question has been asked on the Apple Communities forum, and the consensus there was that it's not possible: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6649250

It's possible that Apple will add this functionality in a later version of their software/OS.